# C++ ignore events for x amount of seconds

Tags: c++, windows

I got a bit of code off github that locks a laptop if the monitor goes to sleep or if the laptop lid is closed. The issue is, if the laptop is started up while the lid is already closed, such as when it's on a docking station for example. The second the code runs it sends the notification to lock the laptop. I have the complied program sitting in the startup folder so the behavior is such that when I login the program starts and then locks the pc immediately if it's closed.

I need to be able to ignore the GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE and GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON events for x amount of seconds once the program is started so that this behavior will stop, but I cannot figure out how to do this. From what I understand the bit of code to ignore all events for x seconds needs to be inserted under the "static LRESULT CALLBACK" portion of the code

Here is the code below:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>

#include <windows.h>

namespace laplock {
namespace {

class LogLine {
public:
    LogLine() {
        if (!logfile) return;
        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
        tm localnow;
        if (localtime_s(&localnow, &now) == 0) {
            *logfile << std::put_time(&localnow, L"%F %T ");
        }
    }

    ~LogLine() {
        if (!logfile) return;
        *logfile << std::endl;
        logfile->flush();
    }

    template <typename T> LogLine& operator<<(T value) {
        if (!logfile) return *this;
        *logfile << value;
        return *this;
    }

    static std::unique_ptr<std::wofstream> logfile;
};

std::unique_ptr<std::wofstream> LogLine::logfile;

std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& stream, const GUID& guid) {
    wchar_t str[128] = { 0 };
    StringFromGUID2(guid, str, sizeof(str));
    stream << str;
    return stream;
}

static void systemError(wchar_t* what)
{
    const DWORD error = GetLastError();
    LogLine() << "Error " << error << " during: " << what;
    static wchar_t buffer[1024];
    const wchar_t* errorMessage = buffer;

    if (!FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        0,
        error,
        0,
        buffer,
        sizeof(buffer),
        0
    ))
        errorMessage = L"(cannot format error message)";
    else
        LogLine() << "System error message: " << errorMessage;

    std::wstringstream message;
    message << L"A system error occured within laplock." << std::endl;
    message << L"Operation: " << what << std::endl;
    message << L"System message: " << errorMessage;
    MessageBox(NULL, message.str().c_str(), L"laplock error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK windowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg != WM_POWERBROADCAST || wParam != PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE) {
        LogLine() << "Window received irrelevant message";
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    if (GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTESESSION)) {
        LogLine() << "Ignoring window message because session is currently remote";
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    const POWERBROADCAST_SETTING* setting = reinterpret_cast<const POWERBROADCAST_SETTING*>(lParam);
    LogLine() << "Received POWERBROADCAST_SETTING " << setting->PowerSetting;
    if (setting->PowerSetting != GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON && setting->PowerSetting != GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE) {
        LogLine() << "Received irrelevant POWERBROADCAST_SETTING";
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    const DWORD* state = reinterpret_cast<const DWORD*>(&setting->Data);
    LogLine() << "POWERBROADCAST_SETTING state: " << *state;
    if (*state != 0) {
        LogLine() << "Irrelevant POWERBROADCAST_SETTING state";
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    LogLine() << "Locking";
    if (LockWorkStation() == 0)
        systemError(L"locking workstation");
    else
        LogLine() << "Locked";

    return 0;
}

static void registerWindowClass(HINSTANCE instance)
{
    LogLine() << "Registering window class";
    WNDCLASSEX windowClass = { 0 };

    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = &windowProcedure;
    windowClass.hInstance = instance;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = L"laplock";

    if (RegisterClassEx(&windowClass) == 0)
        systemError(L"registering window class");
}

static HWND createWindow(HINSTANCE instance)
{
    LogLine() << "Creating window";
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        L"laplock",
        NULL,
        0,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND_MESSAGE,
        NULL,
        instance,
        NULL
    );

    if (hWnd == NULL)
        systemError(L"creating window");
    
    return hWnd;
}

static void registerNotification(HWND window)
{
    LogLine() << "Registering GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON (GUID: " << GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON << ")";
    if (!RegisterPowerSettingNotification(window, &GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE))
        systemError(L"cannot register GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON power setting notification");
    LogLine() << "Registering GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE (GUID: " << GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE << ")";
    if (!RegisterPowerSettingNotification(window, &GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE))
        systemError(L"cannot register GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE power setting notification");
}

static WPARAM messageLoop()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        LogLine() << "Awaiting next window message";
        MSG message;
        BOOL result = GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0);
        if (result == -1)
            systemError(L"getting window message");
        if (result == 0)
            return message.wParam;
        LogLine() << "Dispatching message";
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE instance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR commandLine, int)
{
    if (*commandLine != 0)
        LogLine::logfile.reset(new std::wofstream(commandLine, std::ios_base::app));
    LogLine() << "laplock initializing";

    registerWindowClass(instance);

    HWND window = createWindow(instance);

    registerNotification(window);

    WPARAM result = messageLoop();
    LogLine() << "laplock terminating";
    return result;
}

}
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE instance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, LPSTR commandLine, int cmdShow)
{
    return laplock::WinMain(instance, prevInstance, commandLine, cmdShow);
}
```

Comment: just record the start time and check how long ago it was before processing events?

Comment: Yes I thought of this but I need help with the code, I am not really a good programmer :/

Comment: Please do not tag C++ questions with the C tag.

Comment: book suggestions?